# Save particular sheet/tab from a Google spreadsheet into a folder every month

Tags: google-sheets, automation, scheduling

I'm trying to save a particular tab from a google spreadsheet into a folder and I need to schedule this to happen on the same day every month.

(I need to do that for 20 different sheets to create a backup every month.)

I've seen similar scripts converting to pdf or cvs but in my case I need to extract just one sheet and keep it as a google spreadsheet format inside a different folder.

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

I've written a small piece of code that can handle your needs. I assume that all the files are in one folder (`originalFilesFolderId`) and you want to move them to another (`copiedFilesFolderId`). To achieve this goal you need to use:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

### Step by step

I have split the code in 4 functions:

1. The `main` function: It gets all the files from the `originalFilesFolderId` and calls `process` to start the manipulation.
2. `process`: it open the spreadsheet file, makes a copy and call the other two functions.
3. `deleteSheets`: it deletes all the sheets of the spreadsheet except the first one.
4. `moveFile`: it moves the copied file to the desired destination (`copiedFilesFolderId`)

### Code

```js
function main() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('originalFilesFolderId').getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId()
    process(fileId)
  }
}

function process(fileId) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId)
    var copied = ss.copy("copy of " + ss.getName())
    moveFile(copied)
    deleteSheets(copied)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}

function deleteSheets(copied) {
  var sheets = copied.getSheets()
  for (var i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    copied.deleteSheet(sheets[i])
  }
}

function moveFile(copied) {
  var copiedId = copied.getId()
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copiedId)
  file.moveTo('copiedFilesFolderId')
}
```

### References

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)